# heroku pg:pull from database's on Amazon

Tags: heroku

I having being trying to run pg:pull from my Heroku app which one has a database on Amazon RDS, but the commands keep returning 'app-name has no databases'  even if I use the database url set on my Config Vars .. Am I missing something ?

**try ...**

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL local_database_name --remote app_name
```

**return ...**

```
app_name has no databases
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`heroku pg:pull` is not compatible with databases that aren't hosted on the plaform. This is specified in the documentation:

> pg:pull can be used to pull remote data from a Heroku Postgres database to a database on your local machine. The command looks like this:

You will need to run `pg_dump` and a subsequent `pg_restore` manually to achieve the same result as the automated `pg:pull` command.